# Cordova CLI 5.0.0: Does Cordova CLI 5.0.0 support specifying a custom activity name

Tags: cordova

Does Cordova CLI 5.0.0 support specifying a custom activity name? Anyone can provide the usage? Or workaround methods? As I know the cordova-android/bin/create support --activity-name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to specify the activity name, adding attribute "android-activityName='YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME'" into  tag in /projectpath/config.xml.